# Polycom HDX7000 & Mac Lync 2010: Video call invitation was not accepted

Tags: mac, lync, polycom

We have a Lync 2010 server set up along side a Polycom HDX7000 which acts as a Lync endpoint. This works well for Windows Lync users who can dial and have video conferences with the device.

When a Mac client attempts to connect a connection is made, encryption is enabled and audio works fine, however attempts at video yield "Video call invitation was not accepted." on the client with little other errors.

Mac to Windows works fine. There are no firewalls in play (all on the same LAN).

Anyone have any ideas on where to start looking?

Logs from the polycom that might be relevant:
2011-12-07 17:26:50 DEBUG avc: pc[0]: VIDEO[0]: VideoRouteProcCodecSetConfig CodecConfig: alg unknown profile unknown bRate 0, fRate 0.000000, res 1-SQCIF updtAnnex 0x0 cam
2011-12-07 17:26:50 DEBUG avc: pc[0]: VIDEO[0]:   WxH 128 x 96, maxpkt 0, Sym, Prog, 16x9sar 0 conceal off freezeDec 0

Comment: `VideoRouteProcCodecSetConfig CodecConfig: alg unknown profile unknown bRate 0` looks like a codec error. Is there any codecs that you could install on the OSX systems?

Comment: I was pondering a codec issue but I would have though those to be installed with the Lync client. I'll go looking for one to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer supplied by Polycom support & support forums at Technet.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsclients/thread/97a716db-824e-4e33-b5b5-b0423d3ef605/

"it does not currently work Mac Lync client calling to an HDX.

At present the best workaround is to dial from the Mac Lync client to a LYNC registered RMX instead and have the HDX call to the same virtual meeting room.

There is a known behaviour which we are hoping to address in a maintenance release of HDX in Q1 (2012) but as far as I am aware this has not been committed." - Polycom Tech.

Answer (score 1):

The current release of HDX software 3.0.4 and Lync for Mac 14.0.2 allows direct calling from Lync to HDX.